# How can I implement a default factory for a generic type in a Pydantic BaseClass?

Tags: python, generics, pydantic

I want to create a generic base model, that the field that defaults to the default factory for that type:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
from pydantic.generics import GenericModel, Generic
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Optional

T = TypeVar("T")


class Material(GenericModel, Generic[T]):
    value: T = Field(default_factory=T)


Material[float](value=1)
Material[float](value="1 ")
Material[Optional[float]]()
```

However this is saying returning the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tom/.config/JetBrains/PyCharm2022.2/scratches/tmp.py", line 14, in <module>
    Material[Optional[float]]()
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 340, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
  File "pydantic/main.py", line 1066, in pydantic.main.validate_model
  File "pydantic/fields.py", line 439, in pydantic.fields.ModelField.get_default
TypeError: 'TypeVar' object is not callable
```

Is it possible to have a default factory for a generic type?

Comment: This is not possible in general because there are special typing constructs like `Union` (or an equivalent like your `Optional[float]`, which cannot be instantiated. Try `Optional[float]()` and you'll see. You would have to restrict yourself to instances of `type` and even then this is questionable because there are types with a constructor that you can only call by passing a number of arguments to it, whereas `default_factory` expects it to be a callable taking no arguments. You will have to be more specific with the upper bound of `T` to make this type safe.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg for my usage it will only ever be `float`, `int` or `str` so I think it is okay. I will try and think of some better ways to do this however